# Term for an English language course for technical jargon in a specific field

Tags: word-choice, terminology, technical

What is the proper term for the English language course in which technical and specific terminology related to a particular field of study (Engineering, Medical sciences, Applied sciences etc.) is taught?

I was assuming Technical English to be the right choice but I think that’s not a proper one.

Comment: Technical English is correct indeed, as an all-encompassing term. Why do you think it is not a proper term? Also, it would be better to ask for a term for the type of English instead of a term for the course. It is kind of redundant. Re: Technical English vs. Technical English course. There can be more specific terms like "Engineering English", "Business English" etc. denoting a particular field. If you want to be very specific for a particular field, say mechanical engineering, you can use "English for Mechanical Engineering".

Comment: I can't imagine such a course being taught in the US.  Courses in the US would teach some topic or topics in the field, and the students would learn the vocabulary along the way.  Are we talking about a course for limited English speakers?  Still, I once took a course in the German department, in which the instructor filled the blackboard with vocabulary.  The whole class, every class session.  It was not remotely helpful, and I dropped the class.  Vocabulary out of context -- why not just sit down and read a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

In a comment ermanen answered:

> Technical English is correct indeed, as an all-encompassing term. Why do you think it is not a proper term? Also, it would be better to ask for a term for the type of English instead of a term for the course. It is kind of redundant. Re: Technical English vs. Technical English course. There can be more specific terms like "Engineering English", "Business English" etc. denoting a particular field. If you want to be very specific for a particular field, say mechanical engineering, you can use "English for Mechanical Engineering".

Comment: This is a good comment, but as well as "English for Mechanical Engineering" you also often see "English for Mechanical Engineers", etc.